# How can I use selenium in Raspbian python3?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

**I'm using:**

- Raspberry Pi3
- OS : Raspbian
- language : python 3.5
- Geckodriver : geckodriver-v0.19.1-arm7hf (`usr/local/bin/geckodriver`)
- browser firefox esr (52.6.0 (32-bit))

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.python.org')
```

[image]

Opening the browser is OK, but why did it fail to get URL?

I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

While you initialize the *webdriver* and the *Web Browser* pass the argument **executable_path** along with the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* binary and invoke the proper url as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver   

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='usr/local/bin/geckodriver')    
driver.get("your_url")
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused >>>>> still exist other error T.T

Comment: Update the question with complete error stack trace for analysis please.